# Need to add class but only if element is visible

Tags: jquery

I need to remove all classes of 'no-right-marg' on all #tips li elements.  I then need to hide all those elements with a class of the clicked element's ID.  Then, I need to check which elements are still being displayed and add a class of 'no-right-marg' to every fourth one.  My code below isn't working.  Please see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VCZc4/2/

```
jQuery('#selector li').click(function() {

   colour = '.' + jQuery(this).attr('id');
   jQuery('#tips ' + colour).toggle();
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('inactive');
   jQuery('#tips li').removeClass('no-right-marg');

   jQuery('#tips li:visible').each(function(index){

       if(index %4===0 ){// if divisible by 4
           jQuery(this).addClass('.no-right-marg');

       }            
   });

});​
```

HTML

```
<ul id="selector">
    <li id="brown">button 1</a>
    <li id="green">button 2</a>
    <li id="blue">button 3</a>
    <li id="orange">button 4</a>

</ul>

<ul id="tips">
    <li class="brown">text</li>
    <li class="orange">text</li>
    <li class="blue">text</li>
    <li class="blue no-right-marg">text</li>
     <li class="blue">text</li>
     <li class="orange">text</li>
     <li class="blue">text</li>
    <li class="blue no-right-marg">text</li>
    <li class="green">text</li>
</ul>
​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a "." in your addClass call. Removing the "." fixes your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/VCZc4/5/

I hope that gets what you want.

Comment: thanks for picking that up, it does do something but not the right thing!  It adds the class, but not to every 4th element...

Comment: Ok, so check my new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/VCZc4/10/

Like Sir Jonathan Rowny says, it's zero-indexed. So I added 1 to the index before applying the modulo operator.

How about now?

Comment: ahh so thats what zero indexed means, that it starts at 0.

Comment: Oh muh gawd! My first accepted answer! Now I can finally comment on questions to clarify what the user is asking

Comment: This may be the first time I've ever been referred to as "Sir Jonathan Rowny" Ha.

Answer (score 1):

It's zero-indexed, therefore mod 4 == 3 is what you need.
`if(index % 4 === 0 )` should be `if(index % 4 === 3 )`

Comment: thanks, I've done that but it's still not adding it to every 4th element

Comment: bah, my bad, I meant 3! index should be 3. Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VCZc4/11/